# find: `./folder': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, find

This is the contents of the directory I'm working with:

```
misha@hp-laptop:~/work/c/5$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 misha misha  219 May 20 15:37 demo.c
drwxrwxr-x 2 misha misha 4096 May 20 16:07 folder
-rw-rw-r-- 1 misha misha    0 May 20 16:06 test
```

Now I would like to remove everything from this directory except for the file `demo.c`. Here's the command I've come up with:

```
find . ! \( -name demo.c -o -name . \) -exec rm -Rf {} \;
```

It does exactly what you'd think it would do (meaning, the file `test` and the directory `folder` are gone), but at the same time it also displays the following error message:

```
find: `./folder': No such file or directory
```

Why do you think that is?

Comment: try `find . -depth ...`, find will otherwise try to enter the folder ./folder after having removed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it also displays this error message:
>
> ```
> find: `./folder': No such file or directory
> ```
>
> Why is that?

Because `find` recognizes `./folder` as a directory when it first reads directory `.`, before considering whether it matches the `find` criteria or performing any action on it.  It does not recognize that the action will remove that directory, so after performing the action, it attempts to descend into that directory to scan its contents.  By the time it does that, however, the directory no longer exists.

There are multiple ways to address the problem.  One not yet mentioned is to use the `-prune` action.  This tells `find` not to descend into directories that match the tests:

```
find . ! \( -name demo.c -o -name . \) -exec rm -Rf {} \; -prune
```

That will serve nicely here, and it also has applications in areas where you are not deleting the directory and you do not want to limit the search depth.

Additionally, another way to avoid affecting `.` would be to make use of the fact that `find` accepts multiple base paths to test, that these can designate regular files if you wish, and that during pathname expansion any leading `.` in a filename must be matched explicitly.  If, as in your case, there are no dotfiles in the target directory (other than `.` and `..`), then you can accomplish your objective like this:

```
find * ! -name demo.c -exec rm -Rf {} \; -prune
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your `find` command to this:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -not -name demo.c -delete
```

- `-mindepth 1` ensure that you don't select `DOT`
- `-delete` will delete all files and directories

Comment: Gotcha. I should have written it like this: find . -maxdepth 1 ! \( -name demo.c -o -name . \) -exec rm -Rf {} \;   I forgot about -maxdepth 1.

Comment: `maxdepth 1` will only find files and directories in current directory and you can still use `mindepth 1` to avoid excluding DOT. Your command can be: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -name demo.c -delete`

Answer (score 1):

```
#before


        ls -lrt
        total 4
        -rw-rw-r--  1 user super    0 May 20 09:14 demo.c
        drwxrwxr-x  2 user super 4096 May 20 09:14 folder/
        -rw-rw-r--  1 user super    0 May 20 09:14 test


#Command
        ls -1 | grep -v demo.c |xargs rm -rf 
#After        
        ls -lrt
        total 0
        -rw-rw-r--  1 user super 0 May 20 09:14 demo.c
```

Comment: `ls` is not intended, and not safe, for programmatic use -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Also, `grep -v demo.c` will exclude `foo-demo.c`, which the OP's `-name demo.c` does not; this code is not entirely equivalent to what it's given as a replacement for.

Comment: For a bit of fun, btw, consider that files can contain newlines in their names. Something created with `touch $'cant\ndelete\nme'` will escape the `ls -1 | grep -v demo.c | xargs rm -rf` approach not just on account of `xargs` misbehaving (which it does -- barring extensions such as `-0` or `-d`, it's broken by design), but also because `ls -1` can't represent that name unambiguously in a newline-delimited output stream.

Comment: Also, with a file with spaces in its names, ie. `touch 'hello cruel world'`, the `xargs` usage you gave will try to delete three separate files, `hello`, `cruel`, and `world`, and **not** try to delete that file that actually exists. Similarly, if you have a file with quotes in its names, `xargs` will try to treat them as syntactical.